# Could not draw two graphs in amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

In this working pen [Working Demo](https://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/VmGbqz)

I am able to draw one graph at a time.But if the

`"seriesValueField": ["foo1"]`

is like this then it works fine but if I use like

```
"seriesValueField": ["foo1","foo3"]
```

to plot the two graphs it does not work.I could not figure why it is not working.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The array notation from my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41103116/6106614) requires different code, which you didn't bother to copy into your code. Also, the code from my old answer renames the field to `seriesValueFields`.  I recommend comparing the code again (use a diff tool) to see what was changed so you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @xorspark The problem is when the values of foo1 and foo3 are big then they are able to plot but if they are low then they are not able to plot.In your previous answer the values of foo1 and foo3 are high but here the values of foo1 and foo3 are low.

Comment: Uh, no, that's not the problem at all. Look at the code/diff again between the old version and this version. Heck, copy the new data into my old answer. It still works.

Comment: [Chart image after copying the data into the old answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd8dC.png). Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes I found where I was wrong.The PEN works fine.But now if I keep in my application I get an error ** Error: <rect> attribute width: A negative value is not valid. ("-4")**. Instead of loading from URL if i keep static JSON data it works fine.So I checked with URL data.But it is not null.Any idea?

Comment: I fixed it.it was due to some missing values in the database.Thanx a lot